# JQuery, remove a row befor using as promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm using a rest api where the answers have a prefix for security reasons, i'm not able to change this format.
Example:

```
throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';
{
  "searchResult" : [ {
    "name" : "stackoverflow",
    "found" : true
  } ]
}
```

my request should return a promise, but i want to remove the first row >`throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';`<. And my function is defined as:

```
var searchAPI = function() {

var errorFunction = function errorFunction(x) {
    console.log("searchError:");
    console.log(x);
};
var successFunction = function successFunction(x) {
    console.log("searchSuccess:");
    console.log(x);
};
var parse = function(data) {
    var escaped = data.responseText.replace(/^throw [^;]*;/, '');
    console.log("parsed:");
    console.log(JSON.parse(escaped));
    return JSON.parse(escaped);
};

var fn = function() {

    var searchFor = $j('#searchfield').val();

    console.log("prepare ajay, with: "+searchFor);

    var promise = $j.ajax({
        url : "/service/rest/stackoverflow/search",
        type : "get",
        data : {
            "query" : searchFor
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log('parse');
            console.log(data);
            return parse(data);
        },
        // only for debbuging purpose
        error: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log('parse');
            console.log(data);
            return parse(data);
        }
    });

    promise.done(successFunction);
    promise.fail(errorFunction);
    // promise.always(alwaysFunction);
}
return fn;

};
```

For each request the error is called, i don't know why, the htttp status is 200 (which means OK)

The Browserlog looks thisway:

```
parse
Object {readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
parsed:
Object {"searchResult": Array[1]}
searchError:
Object {readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
```

The request seems to work, bt why is the error function called? and how could 
 I fix this? Where is my failure?

EDIT: i've found the following issue, the return value should be parsed as json, which is not valid at this point:

```
parsererror 
SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token h"}
```

Comment: _bevor_? What you mean?

Comment: sorry my bad its a nativ language problem ;) -> i mean befor

Comment: **Note:** You cannot return data from the middle of an Async call... The function has already exited some time earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally solved, required a [dataFilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
var searchAPI = function() {

var errorFunction = function errorFunction(x) {
    console.log("searchError:");
    console.log(x);
};
var successFunction = function successFunction(x) {
    console.log("searchSuccess:");
    console.log(x);
};
var parse = function(data) {
    var escaped = data.responseText.replace(/^throw [^;]*;/, '');
    return escaped;
};

var fn = function() {

    var searchFor = $j('#searchfield').val();

    console.log("prepare ajay, with: "+searchFor);

    var promise = $j.ajax({
        url : "/service/rest/stackoverflow/search",
        type : "get",
        data : {
            "query" : searchFor
        },
        dataFilter: function (data, type)
             {
                  return parse(data, type);
             },
    });

    promise.done(successFunction);
    promise.fail(errorFunction);
    // promise.always(alwaysFunction);
}
return fn;

};
```

Comment: Now that you know the problem, the code will compact down quite considerably. I'll post as a separate answer.

Comment: Hi Roamer,  While trying to use the data filter I get cannot read responseText property of undefined. Want me to post some code here or am I making some obvious mistake? Please suggest.